# MSGraph - Getting external email conversation from reply

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

My team is building a ticketing system. The goal is when we receive a new email we create a new ticket. All responses to that email are saved on the same ticket.
We have these basic goals working in simple cases, however, there is one case that we are struggling to find a good solution for. A client will email us, which creates a ticket, and we reply back requiring information. The client will send our reply to someone internal to their company. Then they will send the response back to us by replying with "see below". This response will have the conversation between them and their co-worker in the comment section of the email. The comment section will also contain our entire email chain which we don't want to duplicate.
The issue we are having is grabbing the conversation they had from the comment section to include with their response of "see below" and add them to the ticket. The only method we have come up with to solve this is manually parsing the comment section of the email, however, this is error-prone.
Does anyone know of a better way of tracking conversations they send you through the email? 
We are using msgraph internally to send and receive emails and using their apis they have uniqueBody and body, but they don't seem to have a way to break the body up into its different parts.

**What I need** any of these options

*1- get list of unique bodies from the email chain without using conversation Id as it will not be sufficient in some cases.*

*2- get the previous conversation Id of the incoming email. I mean if that email is a list of emails and it forwards to me.*

Comment: Is this in a particular programming language you need this, or only an insight which API's you would need to use?

Comment: any language I just got the idea behind it

Answer (score 1):

```
UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
message.addProperty("InternetMessageId", String.format("%s",uuid.toString()));
```

send InternetMessageId with a unique identifier to grab conversation id
change order only